# Convert my aspx page to png image

Tags: asp.net, png, webbrowser-control

I am generating an aspx page which then I need to convert to png and store it somewhere.

A similiar situation with mine was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012728/how-to-convert-aspx-html-page-to-image-format) but got still no response. I tried also the code that the Swapnil Fegade has asked but the code is looping continually making request to loading page and no conversion is actually being done.

I found some solutions on the web also but they require WebBrowser control which i understood can be used in windows form but i am building a web project.

Can you give me any hint or suggest any article that shows a full example doing this task.
Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This one seems to do what you want:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/htmlimagecapture.aspx